# How do I get a Controls.ItemsControl in an Form

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, user-controls, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a `Controls.ItemsControl`  (actually a `HelixViewport3D`) and would like to add it inside a `Forms.UserControl`.

I already tried `this.Controls.Add(new HelixViewport3D());`
Where this is a derivative from `UserControl`
however this resulted in an error `HelixToolkit.Wpf.HelixViewport3D' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control`. Which makes sense given that they don't inherit anything from one another. Is there a sort of wrapper class in these situations?

```
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


    public partial class HelixForm : Form
    {
        public HelixForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var _3Dcntr = new HelixViewport3D();
            this.Controls.Add(_3Dcntr);//doesn't work

            //what we worked out so far
            var elemHost = new ElementHost();


        }

    }
```

I have also noticed that it's supposed to be possible to host a WPF in a winform using ElementHost.Child but adding this variable/function cannot be found in my example code(missing something?), System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost tells me that System.Windows.Forms.Integration is missing.

Comment: Tell me if you want more info about anything.

Comment: Post the HelixViewport3D code;  Why are you not using a WPF app?

Comment: @juanvan well the HelixViewport3D is a toolkit: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HelixToolkit.Wpf/HelixToolkit.Wpf/HelixViewport3D and I'm using a winform because there is a preexisting application that is nearly finished that uses winforms

Comment: Right-click the References node of your project > Add > pick WindowsFormsIntegration

Comment: Ah now I have an ElemenHost, now to use it.

Answer (score -1):

[Hosting WPF Composite Control in Winform](http://Walkthrough:%20Hosting%20a%20WPF%20Composite%20Control%20in%20Windows%20Forms)

Mixing WPF in a Winforms app is not recommended but Microsoft provides a ElementHost in WindowsFormsIntegration namespace.

Here is a more indepth demo of them working
[Mixing WPF and Winforms](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)

(sorry for the simple answer I have not mixed them before.)

Comment: 'The type of namespace ElementHost cannot be found' no suggestings, same for         System.Windows.Forms.Integration